# Use selection from selectInput in a formula

Tags: r, shiny

I have something like this:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           pickerInput("period", "Period", c("day", "week", "month"), 
                       options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE))))
```

My output (plot) needs to change according to the selection in this input:

```
output$result <- renderPlotly({
    ggplot(data) +
      geom_bar(aes(x = paste(input$period)(birthday)))
```

in othe words the result should be `day(birthday)`, `week(birthday)`, or `month(birthday)`.  What should I do in this instance? My code `paste(input$period)(birthday)` is not the right one.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
output$result <- renderPlotly({
    fn <- switch(
      input$period,
      day = day,
      week = week,
      month = month
    )
    ggplot(data) +
      geom_bar(aes(x = fn(birthday)))
})
```

Comment: thanks @Stéphane. I have another question. What if I want fn to be empty? i.e. in one case:
ggplot(data) +
      geom_bar(aes(x = (birthday)))